# Python script entry point: How to call "__main__2"?

Tags: python

I have inherited a python script which appears to have multiple distinct entry points. For example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__1':
   ... Do stuff for option 1

if __name__ == '__main__2':
   ... Do stuff for option 2

etc
```

Google has turned up a few other examples of this syntax (e.g. [here](https://github.com/mscook/uqbinfpy/blob/master/examples/phylo_examples.py)) but I'm still no wiser on how to use it.

So the question is: How can I call a specific entry point in a python script that has multiple numbered `__main__` sections?

**Update:**
I found another example of it here, where the syntax appears to be related to a specfic tool.
https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/issues/163

Comment: My bet would be the original author wrote multiple test cases and renamed them `__main__1` etc just to keep them *around* for reference, without intending for them to be called. Probably he/she switched between test cases by editing the file and removing the numeral from one of those names at a time.  If you want to switch between cases *without* continually making changes to the source file, I suggest rewriting it so that there's one single `__main__` section, which switches based on a command-line argument retrieved from `sys.argv`

Comment: In the example you linked, there's a comment that might indicate that these are __examples__ of different "main functions". (Note that they aren't actual functions, per se.) This might explain why there are multiple ones. `if __name__ == '__main__'` (without any numbers) is a common idiom to detect whether a script was called (directly) on the command line (vs. imported as a module in another script.)

Comment: @das-g Thanks for pointing out the comment in the link regarding "examples", I think that explains the reasons for doing it in their case. Perhaps my author was also thinking along the same lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html) mentions only **main** as a reserved module namespace. After looking at your sample I notice that every main method seems separate, does its imports, performs some enclosed functionality. My suspicion is that the developer wanted to quickly swap functionalities and didn't bother to use command line arguments for that, opting instead to swap '**main2**' to '**main**' as needed.

This is by no means proven, though - any chance of contacting the one who wrote this in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this. The script in question has about 10 of these sections, so I guess it would be a bit impractical to swap in and out. And sadly I don't have access to the author.

Comment: I'm concluding that either the intention was to sawp in about manually or that there is supposed to be some sort of external script runner such as the `brython` interface mentioned in my update. Either way, it doesn't look like there is any python magic that I've missed here. Thanks again to all for chipping in.